# Display json response from parse.com using handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, getjson, handlebars.js, parse-platform

I would like to pass a json response to handlebars. I have looked at the parse documentation and stackoverflow questions but I cannot seem to figure this out.

This is the response:

```
{"results":[{"address":"755 W. Yale","createdAt":"2013-02-09T01:12:15.732Z","updatedAt":"2013-02-09T01:12:15.732Z","objectId":"JomKPfme5M"}]}
```

This is my handlebars template:

```
<script id="post-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<h1>{{address}}</h1>
</script>
```

This is the script

```
Parse.initialize("xxxxxx", "yyyyyy");

var listingsView = Parse.Object.extend("listings");
var query = new Parse.Query(listingsView);
query.equalTo("objectId", "JomKPfme5M");
query.first({
  success: function(results){

        var source = $('#post-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(results);
    },
    error: function(object, error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Results is an array. Try passing the first element to the template.

```
 var html = template(results[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

And if Hector's answer doesn't work, try this:

```
var html = template(results[0].attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EmberJS  [Ember-Model-Parse-Adapter](https://github.com/samharnack/ember-model-parse-adapter/blob/master/ember-model-parse-adapter.js) is good